# PHP - Warning message is too long to see it?

Tags: php, error-handling, php-7, file-get-contents

I've an issue about a call to `file_get_contents` but I can't see it because it seems to be too long.

The script is running through bash.

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(my_trunked_url) in /somedirectory/somefile.php on line 826
```

Original URL contains 1715 chars, meanwhile my_trunked_url contains 1007 chars.

I'm totally lost about it and I don't know how to see the complete warning in order to get a clarification about the error. This script was running so fine until ~jun/2019 so I think maybe an update of PHP crash it, or some configuration.

By the way, the URL is fine, I can reach it from a client.

Any suggestion, idea or something that can clarify this thing will be preciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error, have to set

```
ini_set('log_errors_max_len', 0);
```

means 0 for no limit.